# Pillow ImageFont is different in docker/Alpine and Ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, python-imaging-library, alpine-linux

I have been created images for my display interface with python Pillow 4.0.0 library.
I prorgamed script which put my text into the pillow picture and after will be converted to bitmap which will be send into the display.

I have put text into the picture with ImageFont function:

```
ImageFont.truetype('my_fonts/font.ttf', font_size)
```

Everythings works fine (in Ubuntu)

[image: Correct image in Ubuntu]

If I run the same programme in Docker Alpine container with the same version of Pillow, the output it is not so good as in Ubuntu:

[image: Docker Apline container]

I hope that is recognizable (it is only 192x64px).
It is not because of fonts - all commands is linked into the same .ttf which is included next to python script.
Also it is not because of docker, when I try docker ubuntu container, result is ok (same as normal first) :

[image]

Unfortunately i have to use Alpine docker container.
Do someone know how to fix it?
Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally when I have compiled older version of freetype (2.4.1 from https://github.com/LuaDist/freetype), output is fine (image from ubuntu = image from Alpine)

```
git clone https://github.com/LuaDist/freetype
cd freetype
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

and after restart the output from pillow truetype is fine!!